# Deleting instance with composite key gives out The property '' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following model:

```
public class EventDetail
{
    [Key][Column(Order = 1)] public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Key][Column(Order = 2)] public int EventId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="")] public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

At first I was trying to update it and apparently you can't update an instance that has 2 primary keys (composite key). And was told that I have to delete it then re insert it again. Now Collected the instance and then tried to remove it from the context like so.

```
EventDetail e = myDbContext.EventDetails
                    .FirstOrDefault(e => e.EventId == 1 && e.UserId == 66);
myDbContext.EventDetails.Remove(e);
```

It would throw out this error:

> The property '' is part of the object's key information and cannot be
>   modified.

Comment: I don't seem to understand what you mean by "ask directly about a correct udpate" when updating it won't allow the changes when I try saving it. I wouldn't ask this if I can update it and save it directly. If you don't understand the question I'm asking then just simply ask to "reconstruct the question as I don't understand it"

Comment: I meant: You said that someone told you that you cannot update an entity which has a composite key. And this is wrong. Of course, you cannot update the entity if you want to *change the key*. But this applies to every entity, also to entities with single key. I understand your question, but I have no clue why you get this exception with the simple code you have shown. Is the exception thrown when you call `Remove` or later on `SaveChanges`?

Comment: When I straight up call the remove it would automatically throw the error. If I do a TryUpdateModel on the model and the "eventid" is changed then it throws the error on the "EventId" eg The property 'EventId' is part of the object's key.. That one happens after I do savechanges. I also tried Deleting from the State myDbContext.Entry(eventDetails).State = State.Deleted. It would throw the same error after saving.

Comment: Is this an MVC application (you mentioned `TryUpdateModel`)? It would probably be helpful if you could show more context, for example the full controller post action. I believe the problem is *before* the code you have shown in your question.